# Make the new keyword optional

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator, javascript-objects

Say I want to create the following API:

```
var api = function(){}

api.prototype = {
  constructor: api,
  method: function() {
    return this;
  }
};
```

Now, this will work like:

```
var myApi = new api();
myApi.method();
```

But let’s say I want to make the `new` keyword optional, so that this will work:

```
api().method();
```

I would out of my head do:

```
var api = function() {
  if ( !(this instanceof api) ) {
    return new api();
  }
};
```

But I was wondering, could this easily be infected somehow, or are there other dangers around using this method? I know that f.ex jQuery don’t do this (they offload the constructor to a prototype method), so I’m sure there are good reason for not doing this. I just don’t know them.

Comment: Your solution looks perfectly okay, I've seen that being used in many places. See [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return an object in the constructor function.

```
function Car(){
   var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
   obj.prop = 1;
   return obj;
}
Car.prototype = {
    method: function (){ }
};

//test
var car1 = Car();
var car2 = new Car();
```

Comment: `Object.create(...)` is especially good since it uses coercion over interrogation and eliminates any references to `this` in the constructor, so you don't need to reason about what `this` is in the constructor context. Methods will still have access to `this` as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Pick one or the other convention. If you want to use objects for your API handles, but don't want people to have to use `new`, use two functions. `Api()` which is a constructor for the objects, and `api()` that's a regular function that just returns a new `Api` instance.

I don't think there's a danger to what you propose, it just seems pointless and I don't like the idea of a function doing two things at once.

Comment: Making `new` optional lets teams use the API in a way that fits their own conventions. Some teams are strongly against `new` because of its gotchas and others use it for its similar feel to languages with inheritance. It would be nice if the API didn't force teams to break their conventions like this. Express.js's `Router` class is a good example of optional `new`.